# Survey Monkey - Retrieve new Responses only via API

Tags: python, surveymonkey

I have a python script that hits the /v3/surveys?pagenum end point. My plan was to calculate the number of responses in the Json and the number of pages (rounded up from 50/page) and compare this with data already brought in from that endpoint. My thinking was if the number of responses in the DB and the Site differed, I could just bring in the last page or pages from the SurveyMonkey API

The code works but what I've found is the new Surveys don't necessarily appear on the last pages They can be on any page. How do I just bring in new Content without re downloading everything. Is this the case with every other endpoint as well? I've looked through the api on the Survey Monkey Site but didn't see anything geared towards getting new content

I have a limited number of api calls and don't really want to download everything each time as this data changes frequently. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Register a webhook. It will tell you when there is a new response.

Comment: Thanks for the direction.

Comment: Feel free to reach out if you need some help.